# Need to remove " from string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am downloading a file in csv format, but happens that all values come like double quotes ("string") text separated by commas. My script is able to display the csv file on a table properly, dividing the columns. However, I want to remove the double quotes " from the strings.
The file loads into html table like this:

"field1" "field2" "field3"

And I want it load like:

field1 field2 field3

I have tried

```
string.replace("\"","") 
string.replace('\"','')
string.replace('\"','') 
string.replace('\"','')
```

None of them worked! How can I do this?

Another issue is, how can I remove the first row of the file when I am importing it.

This is the whole script and neither of answers so far are working:

```
var fileName;
        $('#downloadFile').on('change',function(){
            //get the file name
            fileName = $(this).val();
            fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, fileName.length);
            alert(fileName);
                        

promise = $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"text",
    url: fileName,
    cache:false
});

promise.done(function(data){

    
    var dataArr = data.split("\n");
alert(dataArr);
    //for each line in array
    $.each(dataArr,function(){
        if (this != "") {
            
            
            alert("file in");

            
            this.replaceAll('"','');
            var row = new String("");
            valArr = this.split(",");
            
                row += "<tr>"

            $.each(valArr, function(){
                row += "<td>" + this +"</td>"
            });     

                row += "</tr>"

                $('tbody').append(row);

        }

    });

});

promise.fail(function() {
   console.log('A failure ocurred');
});
```

});

Comment: Can you share some of your input data, the output, and the expected output?

Comment: Are you doing anything with the result returned from `string.replace()`?

Comment: You need to assign the result of the method call to a variable in order to use the replaced value. Also, may be sharing some of the also content within the csv will help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign return value from `replace` method. So your code should look like this:

```
string = string.replace('"', '')
```

What that will do is update the value of string to a new value. In your example you are just calling `replace` method, not actually storing it anywhere.

For even better resould use `replaceAll` which replaces all occurrences instead of first one. Like [Mauricio Lima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14991016/mauricio-lima) said in his answer.

As for other question, why not just skip the first line? You didn't submit any code so we can't really see how your code works.

Comment: Can you send us example data that you are using so we can test it also?

Answer (score 1):

You can use replaceAll javascript function with only doublequote between single quotes:

```js
   const str = 'They said: "This could work"'
   
   console.log(str)
   console.log(str.replaceAll('"', ''))
```

Now, about how you can remove the first line it'll depends how you are importing it and which lib you're using.
I believe your imported data will be in an array... This way, you should just remove the first position value from array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you encounter arises from the fact that if the `.replace` method is called with a string, it will only replace the first occurrence of the match.

You can call the `.replace` with an regex with a global flag

```js
const input = '"string with \\" an escaped quote","another regular string"';
const output = input.replace(/(?<!\\)"/g, '');

console.log(output);
```

I used a negative lookbehind in order to skip a quote that is intentionally stated within the string.

For the *skipping the first line* part, according to your method of getting data, you can simply use

```
var dataArr = data.split("\n").slice(1);
```

to skip the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working!
Instead of making a "replaceAll" before it populates the table, I did it on the string assigned to the table. Like:

```
$.each(valArr, function(){
                row += "<td>" + this.replaceAll('"','') +"</td>"
            });
```

Comment: Then the issue is caused by the confusion about the `.replace` or `.replaceAll` methods, which will return a new string instead of modifying the original string in-place

Comment: Both of .replace and .replaceAll worked. The only difference was that on .replace it would replace only the first time the character appeared on the string like: "name" would return -  name", while on .replaceAll  "name" would properly  return - name.